# iOS pinch gesture to control stack view spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uigesturerecognizer, uistackview

I have a calendar based app

[image: app]

I want the user to be able to pinch to zoom in and out of the calendar. This is my code:

```
let p = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch))
view.addGestureRecognizer(p)

@objc func pinch(gestureRecognizer gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print("----------")
    print("Spacing: \(timeStack.spacing)")
    print("Gesture: \(gesture.scale)")
    var spacing = timeStack.spacing * gesture.scale
    if spacing > 70 {
        spacing = 70
    } else if spacing < 10 {
        spacing = 10
    }
    timeStack.spacing = spacing
}
```

I have a `UIStackView` that contains the labels called `timeStack`, and my code is changing its spacing according to the scale from the gesture.

This is what happens when I run it. It does work but even the most small gesture resize it and it's very unnatural:

[image: gif]

I was wondering how I can improve my code so it's more like the pinch to zoom in the iOS calendar app.
Thank you.

Comment: You must keep the spacing at the beginning of the gesture as the scale is valid for this value only. New spacing is spacing at beginning of gesture x new scale

Comment: Add : gesture.scale = 1.0 after setting new value of time stack.spacing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reset scale each time :

```
@objc func pinch(gestureRecognizer gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print("----------")
    print("Spacing: \(timeStack.spacing)")
    print("Gesture: \(gesture.scale)")
    var spacing = timeStack.spacing * gesture.scale
    if spacing > 70 {
        spacing = 70
    } else if spacing < 10 {
        spacing = 10
    }
    timeStack.spacing = spacing
    // reset gesture scale to prevent cumulative effect
    gesture.scale = 1.0
}
```

Comment: It should be `=` instead of `==` !